# How do you say when you have to work more than usual

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

Let's say you work from 9 a.m. to 4 p.m. But today wi'll have to do extra hours, working longer than you usually do. Are there any good expressions for that?

I'll also ask you to say where the expression is used, if it's AE or BE, If it's from Philly or LA, and so on.

Thank you

Comment: 'Overtime' is given without caveats both in AHDEL and Collins; it is commonly used in the UK.

Comment: 'Overtime' is normal in America, as well. For shift workers, 'double shift' might also have some meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Simply "I'll be working late" would be understood that way.

"I'll be working overtime" would also apply, though *overtime* generally only covers extra hours that are done for extra pay, and not if you get paid a fixed salary regardless.

Comment: Overtime isn't always paid.  If a contract sets out how many hours there are in a normal working week, then anything above that would be overtime, whether or not it is paid.

Comment: @SimonB but many people would not refer to that as *overtime*, though some indeed would.